# Error in the rsyslog.conf file, how to log more than one device?

Tags: linux, dd-wrt, raspberry-pi, syslog

I am trying to log my dd-wrt router and my nas4free device. 
All logs are sent to a spare raspberrypi with a usb disk connected to to store the log files. 
But there is a problem with my rsyslog.conf file. Following code has been added to sent the logs from the devices to the usb stick plugged in the raspberrypi:

```
# logs for the wifi router are saved here:
$template ddwrtlogs,"/mnt/syslog/192.168.1.1.log"
*.* ?ddwrtlogs
#
# logs for the nas4free are saved here:
$template nas4freelogs,"/mnt/syslog/192.168.1.200.log"
*.* ?nas4freelogs
```

This works for the 192.168.1.1 device, but in the 192.168.1.200.log file I find the same logs as the ones in 192.168.1.1.log. It just copy them to both locations. No logs from my nas4free.

I updated both logged devices to sent all logs to 192.168.1.220 (= raspberrypi)

In fact I don't know how to make it work to log two devices. The code is wrong. I can make it work for one device, but if I add a second one in the /etc/rsyslog.conf it just doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it: 

First change the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file. It's quite a long config file, but the only lines you have to change are these: 

`# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514`

`# provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514`

Then go to `/etc/rsyslog.d/` and create files named to the devices where you expect input from. These are my examples:

`touch 10-ddwrt.conf`
`touch 20-nas4free.conf`

And here is the config of each file: 

`$template ddwrt, "/path/to/your/logfile/ddwrt.log"
:fromhost-ip, isequal,    "192.168.1.1" -?ddwrt
& stop`

`$template nas4free, "/path/to/your/logfile/nas4free.log"
:fromhost-ip, isequal,    "192.168.1.200" -?nas4free
& stop`

And the best part is that with this config your local syslog continues to work and remains in `/var/log/`

Bonus: I also changed the `logrotate` config. Log rotation provides a way to limit the total size of the logs retained while still allowing analysis of recent events. 

Go to `/etc/logrotate.d/` and add the devices you receive logs from. Like this: 

`touch ddwrt`

`touch nas4free`

This is the config of both files: 

`/media/pi/USB/Logs/ddwrt.log {
  weekly
  rotate 7
  size 50M
  notifempty
  create
  compress
  postrotate
  invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
  endscript
}`

`/media/pi/USB/Logs/nas4free.log {
  weekly
  rotate 7
  size 50M
  notifempty
  create
  compress
  postrotate
  invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
  endscript
}`